# Get type of product of two different templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Consider the following struct:

```
template<typename R, unsigned short nCols, unsigned short nRows>
struct Matrix{
  std::array<std::array<R, nRows>, nCols> data;
  Matrix<R, nCols, nRows>(){
  }
}
```

Now I want to implement multiplication function, but that might change the type. For example, I could have a matrix of integers and multiply it with a float. Then the new matrix would of course be of the type float. How would I implement this? This doesn't work:

```
template<typename S>
Matrix<R*S, nRows, nCols> mul(const S& s){
  Matrix<R*S, nRows, nCols> result;
  for( unsigned short i = 0; i < nCols; ++i ){
    for( unsigned short j = 0; j < nRows; ++j ){
      result = data[i][j] * s;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

MWE:

```
template<typename R, unsigned short nCols, unsigned short nRows>
struct Matrix{
  std::array<std::array<R, nRows>, nCols> data;
  Matrix<R, nCols, nRows>(){
  }

  template<typename S>
  Matrix<R*S, nRows, nCols> mul(const S& s){
    Matrix<R*S, nRows, nCols> result;
    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < nCols; ++i ){
      for( unsigned short j = 0; j < nRows; ++j ){
        result = data[i][j] * s;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}

int main(){
    Matrix A<int, 2, 2> A;
    A.data[0][0] = 1;
    A.data[0][1] = 2;
    A.data[1][0] = 3;
    A.data[1][1] = 4;
    A.mul(3.141f);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `decltype`.

One possible option is:

```
decltype(std::declval<R>() * std::declval<S>())
```

For brevity, `std::declval<R>()` can be replaced with `data[0][0]`.

The second operand can also be replaced with `s.data[0][0]` *if* you use trailing return type: `auto mul(const S& s) -> decltype(...)`.

---

Alternatively, since `R` and `S` are probably default-constructible, you can get away with

```
decltype(R{} * S{})
```